# Mysterious animation lag on second monitor

Tags: css, electron

So I'm working on this app in electron, and I noticed when I move the app over to my second monitor it seems to lag. Curious what might be causing this- I opened up the dev console, and sure enough- my animations drop from a very comfortable 100-150 fps, to a consistent sub 50 fps. The animation is a height transition, which is poorly handled by the browser, but even this doesn't explain the massive performance drop I see by simply dragging the window over to my second monitor.

I'm considering rethinking the way I handle the animation, to mimic the current look of it using only transforms, but it would be nice to know what's causing the stuttering and lag, since the lag doesn't appear to be specific to my height transition. After digging around for a bit in search of an answer, I'm no closer to anything that might be called a solution. I'm not posting any code with this because none of the animations are handled with JS. It just plain and simple CSS- nothing crazy about it.

To me this seems like it more of an underlying issue with electron itself, or perhaps something strange the OS does.

Comment: ...are your displays plugged into the same graphics card?

Comment: Are both monitors have the same screen resolutions? Can you please confirm? If not then that might be the key part!

Comment: Do both monitors have the same refresh rate setting? Do normal interactions with your second monitor have that laggy feeling as well, or is only the animation? One other thing to note, is if one of your screens is a retina screen with scaling enabled, that could account for the performance hit since it's technically pushing more pixels around.

Comment: one monitor is 1440p, 144hz one is 1080p 60hz. They're both plugged into a 980 ti. It occured to me that maybe the refresh rate might cause this, but it looks like the drop in fps takes the transition well below the 60 hz refresh rate. Also, I should clarify that my main monitor where I DON'T  experience lag, is the 1440p 144hz monitor. Its only on the 60hz 1080p monitor that I experience lag.

Comment: Another clarification- all other interactions with this monitor are normal. I've been using it without issue for almost 2 years now. The issue is so innocuous that my noticing it was basically an accident, so I usually have the app open in my main monitor.